# Pyspark using withColumn to add a derived column to a dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I currently have a dataframe which has the following schema;

```
Year: integer (nullable = true)
Month: integer (nullable = true)
Day: integer (nullable = true)
Hour: integer (nullable = true)
Minute: integer (nullable = true)
Second: integer (nullable = true)
```

I want to basically add an additional column to my dataframe which uses the above date components to construct a datetime type column.  I am currently attempting this using the following;

```
df = df.withColumn("DeptDateTime",getDate(df['Year'], df['Month'], df['Day'], df['Hour'], df['Minute'], df['Second']))
```

I'm struggling with writing the function `getDate` as I want to check the length of Year (currently an Integer) & if it's 2 digits (i.e. 16) then prefix "20" to make "2016" etc.  This needs to be done for each of the date components to essentially construct a date time in the following format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use an if statement to see if `len(str(Year))` is 2 or 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Convert to date**

First, let's create some sample dataset.

```
df_pd = pd.DataFrame([[16, 3, 15], 
                      [2016, 4, 3]], 
                     columns=['Year', 'Month', 'Day'])
df = spark.createDataFrame(df_pd)
```

Then you can write `udf` function to work around your question.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def get_date(year, month, day):
    year = str(year)
    month = str(month)
    day = str(day)
    if len(str(year)) == 2:
        year = '20' + year
    return year + '-' + month + '-' + day
udf_get_date = func.udf(get_date, returnType=StringType())
```

Now, we can apply the our UDF function to 3 columns and use `.cast(DateType())` again so that you have the right format

```
df = df.withColumn('date', udf_get_date('Year', 'Month', 'Day').cast(DateType()))
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----+---+----------+
|Year|Month|Day|      date|
+----+-----+---+----------+
|  16|    3| 15|2016-03-15|
|2016|    4|  3|2016-04-03|
+----+-----+---+----------+
```

### **Convert to date-time format**

This is very similar, I put some variant here where you can use `datetime` also.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df_pd = pd.DataFrame([[16, 3, 15, 10, 34, 14], 
                      [2016, 4, 3, 23, 8, 12]], 
                     columns=['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Second'])
df = spark.createDataFrame(df_pd)

def get_date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second):
    year = str(year)
    if len(str(year)) == 2:
        year = '20' + year
    return str(datetime.datetime(int(year), month, day, hour, minute, second))
udf_get_date = func.udf(get_date, returnType=StringType())
df = df.withColumn('date', udf_get_date('Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Second').cast(TimestampType()))
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----+---+----+------+------+--------------------+
|Year|Month|Day|Hour|Minute|Second|                date|
+----+-----+---+----+------+------+--------------------+
|  16|    3| 15|  10|    34|    14|2016-03-15 10:34:...|
|2016|    4|  3|  23|     8|    12|2016-04-03 23:08:...|
+----+-----+---+----+------+------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Hi.  thanks for the solution, it works great for returning a date.  But really i need to extend this to return a datetime.  Is this possible?

Comment: I amended slightly using .cast(TimestampType() and this worked.

When I did a PrintSchema the following is displayed:

DepartureDateTime: timestamp (nullable = true)

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear! You can also consider accepting the answer so that it helps someone else who are looking at the same solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime module to create your format.
The following code worked for me,

```
from datetime import datetime

def getdate(*args):
    dt_str = '-'.join(map(str,args[:3])) + ' ' +  ':'.join(map(str,args[3:]))
    yr_len = len(str(args[0]))
    if yr_len == 2:
       yr = 'y'
    else:
       yr = 'Y'
    formtd_date = datetime.strptime(dt_str,"%{}-%m-%d %H:%M:%S".format(yr)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return formtd_date

Test input :      
  1.getdate(16,1,2,4,5,6)
  2.getdate(2016,1,2,04,5,58)
output :
  1.2016-01-02 04:05:06
  2.2016-01-02 04:05:58
```

Comment: Hi.  I tried the solution above however got the following error:

time data 'Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Second' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in getdate
  File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Second' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

I am passing calling using the following:

df = df.withColumn('DepartureDateTime', getdate('Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Second'))